# Getting errors while installing node-sass

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, sass, node-sass

When I install `node-sass` for a React project, it gives me the error below. I tried lot of things but none did work. I tried to delete it and install it again, I tried to start a new project but it's still not working. I updated everything to the last version: node.js to `v16.14.0` and npm to `v8.3.1`.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GitHub\XXXXX\Frontend\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GitHub\XXXXX\Frontend\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Documents\\GitHub\\XXXXX\\Frontend\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb download using dist-url https://npm.taobao.org/dist
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GitHub\XXXXX\Frontend\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GitHub\XXXXX\Frontend\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GitHub\XXXXX\Frontend\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GitHub\XXXXX\Frontend\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GitHub\XXXXX\Frontend\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GitHub\XXXXX\Frontend\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GitHub\XXXXX\Frontend\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GitHub\XXXXX\Frontend\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GitHub\XXXXX\Frontend\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GitHub\XXXXX\Frontend\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GitHub\XXXXX\Frontend\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GitHub\XXXXX\Frontend\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python27\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `C:\Python27\python.EXE -c "import sys; print "2.7.15
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '16.14.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb download using dist-url https://npm.taobao.org/dist
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "16.14.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GitHub\XXXXX\Frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GitHub\XXXXX\Frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017 Found installation at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.19041
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.MSBuild.Base
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Using this installation with Windows 10 SDK
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017 using installation: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GitHub\XXXXX\Frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\config.gypi
npm ERR! (node:20452) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GitHub\XXXXX\Frontend\node_modules\node-sass\config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GitHub\XXXXX\Frontend\node_modules\node-sass\common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "msvs"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Documents\\GitHub\\XXXXX\\Frontend\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-G',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2015',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Documents\\GitHub\\XXXXX\\Frontend\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Documents\\GitHub\\XXXXX\\Frontend\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\.node-gyp\\16.14.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\.node-gyp\\16.14.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Documents\\GitHub\\XXXXX\\Frontend\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\.node-gyp\\16.14.0\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Documents\\GitHub\\XXXXX\\Frontend\\node_modules\\node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Documents\\GitHub\\XXXXX\\Frontend\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp verb command build []
npm ERR! gyp verb download using dist-url https://npm.taobao.org/dist
npm ERR! gyp verb build type Release
npm ERR! gyp verb architecture x64
npm ERR! gyp verb node dev dir C:\Users\XXXXX\.node-gyp\16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp verb found first Solution file build/binding.sln
npm ERR! gyp verb using MSBuild: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Documents\\GitHub\\XXXXX\\Frontend\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GitHub\XXXXX\Frontend\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-gyp`.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! Try to update node-gyp and file an Issue if it does not help:
npm ERR! gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues>
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 7

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-14T22_43_35_171Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just change the node version to v14.x.x

Or you may try installing newer versions of node-gpy

Here, read this issue:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/3117

Comment: so much time I spent with wrong versions of  node... thank you!

Comment: Version `14.x.x` is way ancient; returning to it should be the last solution. Consider first the first solution of the below answer.

Answer (score 13):

## First solution

Make sure your `node.js` version is not superior to the [recommended](https://nodejs.org/en/) one. If not, downgrade it, and for that, you could use [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) package from `npm`:

```bash
npm install -g n
n stable
# If one of the commands does not pass, you may need to use sudo
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Then you would wanna use [sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) package instead of [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass), as it's deprecated. And for that, run those commands:

```bash
npm uninstall node-sass --save
npm install sass --save
```

## Second solution

If you need or want `node-sass` for some reason, you should downgrade your `nodejs` version to like `v14`. For that you can use [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) package from `npm`:

```bash
npm install -g n
n 14
# If one of the commands does not pass, you may need to use sudo
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 14
```

Comment: OMG, it's alive) Thank you so much

Answer (score 7):

## Don't use node-sass package

Since `node-sass` is been deprecated, you will have to use its new version, which is `sass`.

You can uninstall the old and install the new one with this command

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with node version incompatibility.
Node sass versions have a compatibility chart here

[Node-sass/node version compatibility chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2Hwj.png)

Both node-sass and libsass have been deprecated in favor of Dart Sass (sass) since October 2020.

In my case I had to downgrade my node version to 14.20.0 since a lot of packages I depend on use 4.x.x

But I can't allow one package to hold my project hostage. so I did some research and found [this article](https://www.openweb.com/blog/preventing-node-sass-or-any-specific-dependency-from-installing) about preventing a package from installing even if it's specified by other dependencies, which is likely what you want

TLDR;

1. Install sass using yarn add -D sass if not installed.
2. Create a folder named dependency-stub in your project root
   2.1. Put a file named index.js in the `dependency-stub` folder
   2.2. then add the lines below

   ```js
   module.exports = {};
   //(which is the stub we will redirect to using resolutions).
   ```

   2.3. `yarn` – add a package.json file to the `dependency-stub` directory
   2.4. Add the lines below to the package.json

   ```json
   {
     "name": "node-sass",
     "version": "0.0.0"
   }
   ```

   `npm` – see note under step 3.
3. In your main package.json, i.e in your project root, add the lines as appears below to the `resolutions`(or overrides if using NPM) section.

```json
{ 
  ...,
  "resolutions": {
     ...
     "node-sass": "file:dependency-stub"
  },
}
```

`npm` – *use the overrides section rather than resolutions, and since npm file urls are relative to the current dependency, you can either use an absolute path to dependency-stub (possibly placing it in your home directory), a URL for a stub module, or a GitHub URL for a stub module*.

4. In tsconfig.json add “dependency-stub” to the include array (to prevent ESLint from throwing errors regarding the file not being in the project).
   *Ignore if you don't use typscript or you use
   and **dependency-stub** isn’t in your project directory, this is not needed.