# Can't install node-sass using npm

Tags: css, node.js, json, sass

I am trying to install SASS compiler node-sass which will compile SCSS code into CSS code. I am trying by watching an online course, doing same things but getting some errors.

```
npm init --yes : creates a json file


npm install node-sass : This command cause the error below
```

[image]
I tried a lot of things to solve and serached for hours but I could not figure out how to get node-sass running.

Comment: Looks like you have some npm packages to update, fix the errors in your report and should come right. The TLS error usually happens on a web server, are you updating on your local machine or remote?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting errors while installing node-sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71119253/getting-errors-while-installing-node-sass)

Comment: No it does'not. problem is fixed with the answer below. Thank you so much for your effort though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

node-sass is deprecated and doesn't support node 18. Replace it with sass

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
```

Comment: Thank you so much. İt was actually sad that the problem was so simple :D Thank you