# Error: node-sass@^3.1.2, ^4.0.0 isn't supported by any available resolver

Tags: sass, yarnpkg, node-sass

When running `yarn install` with yarn version `3.4.1`, I get the following error.

```
➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0001: │ Error: node-sass@^3.1.2, ^4.0.0 isn't supported by any available resolver
    at yf.getResolverByDescriptor (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.4.1.cjs:391:1647)
    at yf.bindDescriptor (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.4.1.cjs:391:1036)
    at Z (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.4.1.cjs:439:6900)
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 0s 987ms
➤ YN0000: Failed with errors in 0s 991ms
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting errors while installing node-sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71119253/getting-errors-while-installing-node-sass)

Comment: changing the node gyp version does not work for me because yarn continues to install the old version, even after specifying the new version in the package json