# i am trying to install npm and i get some errors

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm, sass

this is the first time i am going to use sass. I created a new folder on desktop and opened it on vscode. I entered

> npm init --yes

my package.json file appeared in my folder then i entered

> npm install node-sass

and i got some errors. I am stuck with this error for a week and any of solutions in this platform didn't work for me. Here is the errors i got:

```
PS C:\Users\RUKİYE\OneDrive\Masaüstü\dene> npm install node-sass
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Users\RUKİYE\AppData\Local\npm-cache
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\RUKİYE\AppData\Local\npm-cache'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\RUKİYE\AppData\Local\npm-cache'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\RUKİYE\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache'
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Log files were not written due to an error writing to the directory: C:\Users\RUKİYE\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs
npm ERR! You can rerun the command with `--loglevel=verbose` to see the logs in your terminal
```

Comment: This likely isn't a solution, but you should avoid working on programming projects in a OneDrive folder, as OneDrive [has huge issues with Git](https://gist.github.com/plembo/ff6839d9593ec8afca0ba97d890cce58) which will result in problems down the track (it even caused file system corruption for me a few years ago).

Comment: `node-sass` is deprecated, you should use `dart-sass`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting errors while installing node-sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71119253/getting-errors-while-installing-node-sass)

Comment: As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)

Comment: does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the Turkish characters in the path could contribute to this error if they are causing issues with how the path is being parsed or handled by npm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).